# Can we disallow delete of entire datastore in Yang Model for a particular value of a leaf node?

Tags: command-line-interface, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf, yang

For Example:

```
leaf parent
{
 leaf value2
 {
    tailf:info "value2";
    type string;
    mandatory true;
    default "Enabled";
 }
 leaf value3
 {
    tailf:info "value3";
    type int32;
    mandatory true;
    default "1";
 }
}
```

If value2 is Disabled we will not allow deleting this config(the parent node itself should not be allowed to delete).

Tried must statements not able to figure out conditions

Comment: When you say "this config", do you actually mean "this leaf"? Or do you expect an entire datastore to become read-only based on the value of this leaf?